# At what times can I visit Dr Shrunk?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I know I can visit the nightclub starting at 8pm. But if I'm trying to learn emotions, at what time should I show up to catch Dr Shrunk setting up? I've tried absurdly early (before  I go to work, at 8am) and he's not there, so I know it's not "anytime the club isn't open".

Comment: I go around 12 on weekdays, seems to work. Don't know the specifics though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He will tell you a joke anytime between 12pm (noon) and 8pm on any day of the week. I know this from experience, I just got my last joke!

Comment: He doesn't seem to be answering when I go just before 8, so I think he closes at some point... unless that was because I'd never met him before?

Comment: If you haven't talked to him yet, that is probably why.  I know I've gotten him to tell me a joke between 7pm and 8pm on several occasions.